# APN/iOS: when do device tokens become invalid?

Tags: php, ios, swift, cron, apple-push-notifications

My iOS app should support push notifications through APN and I have uninstalled and re-installed my app into my iPhone 6S three times which means that I have three different couples `<device-id, device-token>` in an apposite MySQL table of which only the last (the maximum id) is the most recent and thus the valid one. Then, I wrote this PHP script which I found here in StackOverflow which should return the invalid tokens to be deleted from the database:

```
<?php
  $cert_file = './superbar-development.pem';

  $stream_context = stream_context_create();
  stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $cert_file);

  $apns_connection =   stream_socket_client('feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $error_code,       $error_message, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);

  if($apns_connection === false) {
    apns_close_connection($apns_connection);
    error_log ("APNS Feedback Request Error: $error_code - $error_message", 0);
  }

  $feedback_tokens = array();

  while(!feof($apns_connection)) {
    $data = fread($apns_connection, 38);
    if(strlen($data)) {
      $feedback_tokens[] = unpack("N1timestamp/n1length/H*devtoken", $data);
    }
  }
  fclose($apns_connection);
  print_r($feedback_tokens);
?>
```

But I always get and empty array which means that the first two couples `<device-id, device-token>` have not been detected as invalid yet. How much time does it take to do that? I am asking this because I have seen that connecting to and reading from `feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196` is very very slow so I wouldn't like to cron to do it every time it has to send push notifications. Do you know anything about this? Thank you.